# JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of Score out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I have problem to Deserialize instance of Score in ServiceRESTClient.

Here is my JPA Entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery( name = "Score.getBestScores",
        query = "SELECT s.game, s.player, s.points, s.playedon, s.id FROM Score s WHERE s.game = :game ORDER BY points DESC")
public class Score implements Comparable<Score>, Serializable {

    private String game;

    private String player;

    private int points;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date playedon;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    public Score(String game, String player, int points, Date playedon) {
        this.game = game;
        this.player = player;
        this.points = points;
        this.playedon = playedon;
    }

    public Score(){}
...
```

On server I am using REST API to get JSON output from this entity(using JPA entityManager):

//http://localhost:8080/rest/score/mines

```
@GET
@Path("/{game}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Score> getBestScores(@PathParam("game") String game) throws ScoreException {
    return scoreService.getBestScores(game);
}
```

If I am using postman to get Scores(http://localhost:8080/rest/score/mines) I get output:

```
[
  [
    "mines",
    "Ondrej",
    96,
    "2017-04-24",
    38
  ],
  [
    "mines",
    "Ondrej",
    94,
    "2017-04-24",
    13
  ]
]
```

but If I try to get output from Client:

```
@Override
public List<Score> getBestScores(String game) throws ScoreException {
    try {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        return client.target(URL)
                .path("/" + game)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(new GenericType<List<Score>>() {
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ScoreException("Error loading score", e);
    }
}
```

I always get the same error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of sk.tuke.gamestudio.server.entity.Score out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@76165093; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:875) ~[jersey-client-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$800(JerseyInvocation.java:92) ~[jersey-client-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$3.call(JerseyInvocation.java:724) ~[jersey-client-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228) ~[jersey-common-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444) ~[jersey-common-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:720) ~[jersey-client-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:430) ~[jersey-client-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:321) ~[jersey-client-2.23.2.jar:na]
    at sk.tuke.gamestudio.server.service.ScoreServiceRestClient.getBestScores(ScoreServiceRestClient.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try `new TypeReference<List<Score>>() {}`?

Comment: What do you mean? Just replace this: `new GenericType<List<Score>>() {
                }` ?

Comment: Yes, try replacing `GenericType` with `TypeReferene`?

Comment: Doesn't work... IntelliJ write me that there is not so method with such parameter type...

Comment: I tried this solution: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/ and it return right output for me so I think that the problem is just in JSON format because in JSON array look like [...] and object look like: {} so output should look like: [{}{}{}...] so in my case right output is:

[
{
    "mines",
    "Ondrej",
    94,
    "2017-04-24",
    13
  }
]
Am I right?